# detect middle (rotary) button click on android waer

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am developing an app for Android Wear and are using the hardware buttons.
I can manage to catch the buttons with the onKeyDown override:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
      Log.i("CLICK", Integer.toString(keyCode));
      if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STEM_1) {
          // Do stuff
          return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STEM_2) {
          // Do stuff
          return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STEM_3) {
          // Do stuff
          return true;
        }
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

I would also like to catch a click on the middle (rotary) button,
but when I click this button, the watch is going back to the default 'home'(watchface)-screen,
and no event is being logged.

I can manage to catch the rotary scrolling, but it's the click I'd like to use.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL && RotaryEncoder.isFromRotaryEncoder(ev)) {
            // // Note that we negate the delta value here in order to get the right scroll direction.
            // float delta = -RotaryEncoder.getRotaryAxisValue(ev)
            //         * RotaryEncoder.getScaledScrollFactor(getContext());
            // scrollBy(0, Math.round(delta));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onGenericMotionEvent(ev);
    }
```

Is this possible, or is it impossible to override the functionallity of the middle watch button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU It should be getting `KEYCODE_HOME` as key event on pressing RSB in `onKeyDown()`.
If it is the case then it is controlled by Android framework only and apps can't do anything with it.

Here is the official description

> Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and
>   is never delivered to applications.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME